# Sitecore 7.2 MVC5+Autofac+Wffm Validation Errors

Tags: sitecore, autofac, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've been working with a Sitecore 7.2 framework that uses Autofac for its dependency injection. A project I'm working on was recently updated to the latest Wffm (2.4 rev. 141008) for full MVC5 support. We encountered a problem where forms submitted via javascript would return the model with string arrays for the values. The Wffm library was then throwing errors since it is expecting a string for the value. This issue does not happen when doing a standard submission to the page without client side validation.

Using a vanilla Sitecore install, installing the latest wffm and including Autofac as the dependency resolver has revealed that it's the interaction between wffm and Autofac that is causing the issue. I'm literally only setting the resolver in the application PreApplicationStartMethod.

It seems like the resolver is overriding whatever wffm wants to use to handle it's submissions. Is there a particular interface that I need to register so that web forms can use it's native serialization code or something?

Comment: What is the value of the Resolver BEFORE you assign yours?

Comment: It's the standard mvc resolver before hand (System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.DefaultDependencyResolver).
The Wffm package has the simpleinjector library included. I'm having a look at whether that will resolve correctly.

Comment: I noticed the simpleinjector indeed and am guessing that having multiple resolvers is causing the issue. I hope you can locate the issue.

Comment: Did you ever managed to fix this?

Comment: We ended up refactoring to allow the use of simpleinjector in our internal library. It gave us the opportunity to do some long overdue decoupling.